# How to have long hyphenations around line of text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules, cv

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Large 
-----------------------------
Education 
----------------------------}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I'm working on my `resume`, and I would like to create a section title called **Education** where the lines to the left and right of the text extend to the margins. Currently I'm manually typing out all the individual `"-"`s, which is very inefficient. Also, the actual output is nowhere near perfect. As you can see below, the last `"-"` is a bit off from the rest.

[image]

Comment: Did you try [How can I fill a line from the left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305039/14500) or [\hrulefill with customized rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154772/14500)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to place horizontal lines or rules around a title. Here are some examples taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347893/how-to-make-text-in-a-middle-of-a-line-text-example?rq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243651/center-text-between-horizontal-lines-extending-to-the-margin-on-either-side).

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% First command
\makeatletter
\def\myrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height .7ex width 1ex depth -0.6ex\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

% Second command
\newcommand{\textbetweenrules}[2][.4pt]{%
  \par\vspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \dimen0=.5\dimexpr\ht0+#1\relax
    \dimen2=-.5\dimexpr\ht0-#1\relax
    \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2\hfill
    ~#2
    \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2\hfill
  }\par\nopagebreak\vspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\noindent\hrulefill ~Education~\hrulefill
\medskip
\noindent\myrulefill ~Education~\myrulefill\par
\medskip
\textbetweenrules{Education}
\end{document}
```

The first example is with an ordinary `\hrule`, which lies at the bottom of the row. The second and third use some predefined commandsas specified.

[image]
In the command `\textbetweenrules{Education}` you can modify the rule widh by putting the parameter between brackets. For example `\textbetweenrules[3pt]{Education}`